# Zend Framework password field rendering as 'text' instead of 'password'

Tags: php, html, forms, zend-framework2

I'm following along with the Zend Framework 2.0 by example, and working on the Forms chapter now. Everything seems to be working fine, except that my 'password' and 'confirm password' fields don't seem to be rendering correctly. Here is an excerpt of my `RegisterForm.php` file where I am defining the password field

```
class RegisterForm extends Form 
{
public function __construct($name = null) 
{
    parent::__construct('Register');
    $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
    $this->setAttribute('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');

       ...

        $this->add(array(
       'name' => 'password',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type' => 'password',
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Password',
        ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'required' => 'required'
        ),
        'filters' => array(
            array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
        ),
    ));
```

but when it is rendered in the browser, I am getting this when I view the page source...

```
<dd><input name="password" required="required" type="text" value=""></dd>
```

I'm quite sure I've got the code down from the book correctly, but I'm not sure if there's another step where I'm accidentally overriding the RegisterForm.php file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why are you overriding your attributes? It should be:

```
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'password',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Password',
        ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'type' => 'password',
            'required' => 'required'
        ),
        'filters' => array(
             array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
        ),
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'attributes' => array(
    'type' => 'password',
),
// ...
'attributes' => array(
    'required' => 'required'
),
```

Think a second...